# Finding the percentile in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Data-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'city':['abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc'],'zone':['AA','AA','CC','CC','DD','DD'],'date':['1/1/2020','1/2/2020','1/1/2020','1/2/2020','1/1/2020','1/2/2020'],'D':[22,33,32,76,44,66]})
```

Now I want to search through for a particular city and date and find the 10 percentile of column 'D' and if the particular zone is below it add the row to a datagram.

for example-

for the first `city` 'abc' and `date` 1/1/2020 we have three zones 'AA','CC' and 'DD' which have the corresponding 'D' column as 22,32 and 44. So the 10th percentile is 24 so first row gets appended to new dataframe and so on.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can define lists of unique cities and dates and create an empty dataframe (`new_df`). Then simply loop through `cities`, `dates` and append the 10th percentile row(s) to `new_df`:

```
cities = list(df.city.unique())
dates = list(df.date.unique())

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for city in cities:
    for date in dates:
        d = df[(df.city==city) & (df.date==date)]
        mx = d.D.max()
        mn = d.D.min()
        v = mn + (mx-mn)/10
        new_df = new_df.append(d[d.D<=v])
```

---

```
new_df
    city    zone    date        D
0   abc     AA      1/1/2020    22
1   abc     AA      1/2/2020    33
```

Comment: i wanted a loop through city and date and not for a specific city and date

Answer (score 0):

This is `groupby().quantile`:

```
df.groupby(['city','zone'])['D'].quantile(0.1)
```

Output:

```
city  zone
abc   AA      23.1
      CC      36.4
      DD      46.2
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) with [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) that will give row-wise the 10th percentile of the group, and then use `loc` to get only the rows where the value in D is lower than or equal (`le`) to this 10th percentile value.

```
print (df.loc[df['D'].le(df.groupby(['city', 'date'])['D']
                           .transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.1))), :])

  city zone      date   D
0  abc   AA  1/1/2020  22
1  abc   AA  1/2/2020  33
```

Comment: My actual dataset has more columns.. is that why when I am running this code there its giving error?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob what do you mean more columns? in the groupby? on which you want to perform the quantile?